# What is the différence between #include <iostream.h> and #include <iostream>?

Tags: c++, iostream

What is the difference between

`#include <iostream.h>`

and

`#include <iostream>`

?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Before C++ was even standardised, the I/O library was developed as `<iostream.h>`. However, that header has never been a standard C++ header. Some older compilers continued to distribute the `<iostream>` header also as `<iostream.h>`. Use `<iostream>` because it is guaranteed by the standard to exist.

It's worth noting that the only standard headers that end with `.h` are the C standard library headers. All C++ standard library headers do not end with `.h`.

Comment: During the transition period, there were compilers which delivered a `<iostream.h>` which included `<iostream>` (plus a number of `using`, so that you didn't need `std::`); there were others whose `<iostream>` included `<iostream.h>` (and the compiler was hacked to make `std::` the same as `::`).

Comment: Extra question about naming conventions: why it is named `<iostream>` instead of `<stdiostream>`? Or vice versa: why it is named `<stdexcept>` instead of `<except>`?

Answer (score 4):

`<iostream>`  is the usual header

`<iostream.h>`  is the old header, not longer supported by some compilers

Answer (score 0):

It just depends on the name of the file provided by your toolchain.
Some (old) compilers use `.h` files.
Modern compilers usually use `<iostream>` (without the `.h` extension).